# In python, how do I open a new window by clicking a button in a main window using .py files created from .ui files made in QtDesigner?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have two .py files created from .ui files made in QtDesigner. One is a main window for the program, and the other is a widget that allows users to input information and I'm calling it the "evaluation" widget.

I have a button in the main window called "btn_StartNew", which is meant to open the widget window to allow the user to start a new evaluation. I'm having troubles with opening the main window, and adding the function to the "btn_StartNew" button that opens the "evaluation" widget.

The code I have right now opens both the main window and the evaluation widget in the same window when I run the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from wid_Main import Ui_wid_Main
from wid_Eval_v2 import Ui_wid_Eval

class Win_Eval(QtGui.QWidget):
     def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Win_Eval, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui=Ui_wid_Eval()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)     


class Win_Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Win_Main, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui=Ui_wid_Main()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        #RUN "start new eval" button
        self.ui.btn_StartNew.clicked.connect(self.btn_StartNew_click)
        self.dialog = Win_Eval(self)

   def btn_StartNew_click(self):
        self.dialog.show()


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Win_Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Where wid_Main and Ui_wid_Main are the main window file and the main window class, respectively. And wid_Eval_v2 and Ui_wid_Eval are the evaluation widget file and class, respectively.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change:

```
self.dialog = Win_Eval(self)
```

to

```
self.dialog = Win_Eval()
```